# confidence interval for the difference between 2 changes in proportions

Tags: confidence-interval, pre-post-comparison

I wonder if anyone can advise on how I can calculate a confidence interval for the difference between 2 quantities that are themselves a change in proportions. To be clearer if I have two groups (say active and control) and in each a certain number out of a total are ill (say) both pre and post a time period. so for active I can look at the change in proportions over the period and the same for the control. It possible there is some pairing (to some extent some people will occur pre and post - I want to ignore this).
I wondered if I could use the group x prepost interaction terms from a model where I specify each person as having a binary endpoint. Or alternatively bootstrap but sampling for each of the 4 proportions (using the sample proportion) and then find the middle 95% of the difference between the proportion changes in the bootstrap samples.
many thanks